# Can Twitter API search for all latest tweets from a country, rather than a geo co-ordinate?

Tags: geolocation, twitter, twitter-search

I want to search for the latest Tweets from the UK but currently the closest I've found is being able to search a radius from a given co-ordinate e.g.
`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?geocode=51.503355%2C-0.127564%2C50mi` returns tweets from a 50 mile radius of the centre of London.